# Print statement not working on CodeBlocks for Mac

Tags: c

I've recently downlaoded code blocks for mac and for some reason my code compiles with no errors but when I try to run it in terminal to see if it prints it doesn't print anything. This is my code. I have already downloaded x code and my program is able to build in code blocks but print f will not work. Can someone please give a solution to this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the program run so fast that a terminal window opens and closes before you have a chance to see anything happen? If so, get an input before ending the program.

Comment: How exactly did you determine that it didn't print anything? Where did you direct its output?

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: While using an IDE like CodeBlocks is fine, if you want to learn how to compile and run programs, just open a terminal. You can compile and run anything you need from the command line (and as a fringe-benefit, you actually learn what compiler options do -- so you can then tell your IDE how you want it done) [Building from the Command Line with Xcode FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html)